# Define context parameters in different way than web.xml

Tags: servlets, context-param

Let's say I have servlet based web application which uses `web.xml` to define context parameters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>logging.path</param-name>
        <param-value>target/logs</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

Is there any alternative how one can define context params?

The reason I am asking is that you have e.g. `@WebFilter` annotation to replace `<filter-mapping>`s in `web.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You can define context paramaters programmatically by setting [setInitParameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setInitParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

later, fetch it by [getInitParameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter(java.lang.String))